# How to get dialogue state that which slot it is filling ?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

​this.event.request.dialogState This give us state like started , completed and in progress how can i get the state that for which slot it is filling ? For ex i have 3 slot name , age , address so how to get the information in dialogue state that it is filling for age slot and than i want to give user multiple choices when they are on age slot for ex when alexa asked the age it should prompt for age under 18 , between 20 -20 , above 50 so how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

when receiving in progress state, inside

```
this.event.request.intent.slots
```

there are variables sth like COMPLETED of CONFIRMED something that can be used to track the state of the slots for each slot